# What's an elegent way to describe a phrase that flows nicely because its vowels and consonants alternate?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, linguistics, phonotactics

What know ye of an elegant way to describe a word or phrase that either perfectly or close-to-perfectly alternates vowels and consonants, either in sound or spelling?

Usage of such a word might include:

- Honorificabilitudinatatibus is the longest ____________ic word in the English language.
- People tend to call my parents "Jake and Alex" more often than "Alex and Jake." I think that's either because the former is a di-trochee or because it's a _________.
- In non-_________ phrases, some consonants can become totally elided into their neighbors if the speaker's not careful. "Alex and Jake," said /'alɪksɛn'dʒɛɪk/ in my area, becomes vocally indistinguishable from both "Alex an Jake" and "Alex and Zhake."

I don't even know where to start with a dictionary or thesaurus search.

I'm hoping we can use formal or technical language for this. A compound word or phrase would be totally acceptable.

Comment: ***Mellifluous***.

Comment: I think we're verging on trivia here. _Arbitrarily invented 'words'_ (almost certainly a contradiction in terms) is a give-away.

Comment: "Open syllable."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I pose this question because it's getting difficult to discuss this topic in an essay. "Phrase that alternates consonants and vowels" is kind of a mouthful. (I've removed the phrase "other than the arbitrarily invented word _alternoconsonantovocal_" from where to start with a dictionary or thesaurus search.)

Comment: Regrettably, "banana panorama" hasn't been adopted for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're observing can be described through [phonotactic](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonotactics-phonology-term-4071087) notation, with C for consonant and V for vowel. So a CVCV word would involve a consonant, vowel, consonant, and vowel (ex. *data*, *pity*, *parry*) formed of two CV syllables. To see the notation in action, see e.g. Brett Kessler and Rebecca Treiman, "[Syllable Structure and the Distribution of Phonemes in English Syllables](http://spell.psychology.wustl.edu/SyllStructDistPhon/CVC.html)."

After some searching and checking some rhetorical dictionaries, I have found no single term for what you describe. For example, Scottish philosopher Alexander Bain, in the 19th century guide *[English Composition and Rhetoric](https://books.google.com/books?id=p65gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=rhetoric%20alternating%20consonant%20and%20vowel&source=bl&ots=n-Ia2nZN9c&sig=ACfU3U3ILDDFkocHZ_95PtVWTCrm91mPrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs6qKS4orkAhXvg-AKHR_vC4QQ6AEwD3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (1867), had no term for such alternation but praised it as "more agreeable." It could also be described generally as **[euphonious](https://books.google.com/books?id=IKlHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=rhetorical%20term%20alternating%20consonant%20vowel&source=bl&ots=VJfqfx1zW4&sig=ACfU3U0VrQ8KqhKcOoFNmmo9OzyQaenYUg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj916z35orkAhVvTt8KHdbTAKAQ6AEwDXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)** (John Seely Hart, 1886), or pleasing to the ear. If you want a more technical account, I would resort to description: "a word made of alternating vowels and consonants," "a word formed of CV syllables," and so on.